# Can anyone tell me what blackletter font this is?

Tags: font-identification, blackletter

[image: Snow white and the seven dwarfs original logo]

Hi, can anyone please tell me what blackletter font Disney have used int his original Snow White & the seven dwarfs logo please?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please read [our requirements for font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/2611) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Computer fonts existed only between the ears of propellerheads when Disney made his version of Snow White. I guess their army of artists contained also lettering specialists who were able to create original works. The value of owning every letter in a soon famous name was surely well known. But that hasn't prevented typographists of today to make Disney inspired fonts. Here's one collection https://www.fontspace.com/category/disney. Unfortunately I do not know an exact match.